# Docker container + postgresql interface dependency

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking

I'm new to the docker world and I came up with a situation that I don't know how to solve.

Basically, I've a container running `wiki.js` within an Ubuntu 20.04 server, associated to a docker network created only for such container:

```
sudo docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 my.wiki.net

sudo docker run -d --net my.wiki.net --name my.wiki \
                -restart=unless-stopped \
                /* other args */ \
                requarks/wiki:2
```

On the other hand, within the container, the wiki is set to connect to `172.18.0.1` to speak with postgresql.

Finally, postgresql is set to listen to `localhost` and `172.18.0.1`:

```
listen_address = 'localhost,172.18.0.1`
```

However, at machine reboot, `postgresql` is launched before `docker` and, since `my.wiki` container is not run yet, the interface `172.18.0.1` doesn't exists in the host machine and postgresql cannot bind to it.

It occurs to me some potential solutions but none of them work or are of my taste:

- Edit the `postgresql.service` config file of `systemctl` to add an `after` relationshit to make sure `docker` is launched before, so the interface exists:  I don't like this solution because I don't want to created such direct dependency between services. I want to make everything works in the most lazy way as possible.
- To configure `postgresql` with a retry strategy so it tries to bind to it during some interval of time, enough for the interface to be created: I think `postgresql` doesn't provide such kind of customization (I searched for it without success).
- Make `postgresql` binds to any (`*`) interface: yeah, it will definitely work (and I still have `pg_hba.conf` as a second layer of protection), but I'm not sure about its implications from a security or even performance perspective. Would you recomend this approach to me?
- Manually create a system-wide interface persistant through reboots and make the `wiki.js` container have visibility to it: first I don't know how to do that, second, it has some impact from a design point of view: if I run a second container requiring postgresql, what's the semantics of the previously created interface?

  - It's an interface for `wiki.js` database access only, and so I must manually create a second interface for the second container to follow the design. The drawback is: if you have `n` containers, you will end up with `2 * n` interfaces, `n` for the external visibilities of the containers (because, unless they need to communicate each other, I'll prefer to create a separate docker user-custom subnet for each one), and `n` for their DB communications.
  - It's an unique interface for all containers requiring `postgresql` access, so it's a, kind-of, "postgresql-docker` localhost: yeah, I could live with that, although I don't know how to do that (I don't know how to properly create interfaces), and also, it seems like I'm changing my design to fit the defect, instead of solving the defect (the interface doesn't exists when postgresql runs and it won't retry later).

So, any advice, alternative design, or the steps to achieve any of my proposals above will be welcome.

Comment: another potential solution - move Postgres to Docker.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov But how can I make sure these container are also initialized in the correct order?

Comment: If you use docker-compose then you can specify dependency. Also, I do not know how is `wiki` app implemented but if it fails when PG is not available then Docker will try to restart it so eventually it will connect PG when it is up.

Comment: Or `wiki` could be implemented in a way that it tries to reconnect PG so eventually it will be fine. You can test it even with current PG - just disable it and restart box

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov It just the oppposite, the wiki tries to connect multiple times, the problem it's that PG is not listening to the address the wiki is trying to connect, because the corresponding interface didn't exists when PG run, because the interface was created when the wiki container was launched, and that happen AFTER PG. So I have to restart PG instead once the container is run.

Comment: If wiki tries to connect multiple times than you can move PG into the docket and do not care about order - eventually, PG will be up and wiki connects it.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov PG is up all the time. At machine restart, PG binds to the `listen_addresses`. I have set two: localhost and 172.18.0.1 but 172.18.0.1 doesn't exists yet. It then fails to bind to 172.18.0.1 but binds to localhost. When docker starts later, it, in turns, starts the container and the interface 172.18.0.1 is added. The container then tries to talk through 172.18.0.1 but nobody answers. Then, I restart PG and now it binds succesfully to it alongside localhost. Finally, the container, that has a retry policy, will sucessfully talk to PG at next attempt.

Comment: I was talking about "another potential solution - move Postgres to Docker." and "But how can I make sure these container are also initialized in the correct order? ". If wiki retires multiple times then Docker in PG will be fine, no matter what initialization order is.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Yeah I think I got you know. I have to run a PG docker image and make sure the PG container belongs to the same user-custom docker subnet as the wiki and docker should take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

SystemD service descriptors do also allow for "Before" clauses. That transposes into an After clause of the other service mentioned.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Addtionally, you may want to split off the network creation into a Type=oneshot service and have your wiki.js service a double dependency on postgres and that network-oneshot unit.